# Regex is matching odd spaces

Tags: python, regex

I need to match roman numerals in text. For example `Star Wars VII The Force Awakens`
I use this expression `(?:^|\s)(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(?:\s|$)` but it matches VII with spaces, i.e. `_VII_`

I tryed `(?<=^|\s)(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(?=\s|$)` but get exeption `error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

I think the problem is with non-capturing groups. If i use `match` or `search` - it returns only number, but with `sub` - it replace both non-capturing groups and capturing group (number with spaces).

The goal is to match roman numerals in text with space or nothing (start/end of line) before/after and not as part of word.

Comment: Do you only want to match the roman numbers IX, IV, I, II, III, VI, VII, VIII?

Comment: Yes. Nothing more the 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the alternation (`|`) outside the lookbehind:

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})(?=\s|$)
```

[See it in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5E%7C(%3F%3C%3D%5Cs))(IX%7CIV%7CV%3FI%7B0%2C3%7D)(%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%24)&test_string=Star%20Wars%20VII%20The%20Force%20Awakens&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

---

Alternatively, you can just replace the lookarounds with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b
```

Comment: In first example i'll use second group?
The second example doesn't work

Comment: note that `\b(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b` will also match the empty string. I am currently trying to figure out how to prevent that.

Comment: @DigitalGod, updated the first regex to use non-capturing group so you don't have to change anything. For the second one - could you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @DigitalGod, to make it not match empty strings, you can split `V?I{0,3}` into two parts. Like `VI{0,3}|I{1,3}`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thx